# Unix Shell Script With Command Arguments To Open Another Program With Those Arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following Unix Shell Script. I'm am accepting arguments to the shell correctly. I'm trying to take those arguments and running the ./TCPHost.out program.

This ./TCPHost.out program takes two command line arguments to successfully run. I need to get those arguments from the execution of the shell, and pass them to the TCPHost.out COMMAND1 COMMAND2.

I am receiving the following error (Makes sense because it believes it's a file, not a file to be ran with arguments):

Error In Terminal: The file /Users/71021180/Desktop/Murph Chat Assignment/TCPHost.out 127.0.0.1 5001 does not exist.

Can someone explain this better to me? I'm new to Unix Shell Scripting.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World

echo Total Number of Argument Passed: "$#"

echo Arguments List -
echo $1
echo $2

open -a Terminal ./TCPServer.out
open -a Terminal ./TCPHost.out" "$1" "$2
open -a Terminal ./TCPClient.out
```

Comment: try `.. Terminal <(./TCPHost.out $1 $2)`

Comment: No, the shell script is in the same directory as the executables

Comment: Thank you @karakfa! That worked!